# How to refactor to reduce the duplicated code?

Tags: java, generics, primitive

I have the main abstract class GLSubBuffer to model a subpart of a buffer :

```
@Getter(value = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public abstract class GLSubBuffer<T extends Buffer> {

  private final T buffer;
  private final int position;
  private final int capacity;

  public GLSubBuffer(T buffer, int position, int capacity) {
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.position = position;
    this.capacity = capacity;
  }

}
```

Here the class for a subpart of FloatBuffer

```
public class GLSubFloatBuffer extends GLSubBuffer<FloatBuffer> {

  public GLSubFloatBuffer(FloatBuffer buffer, int position, int capacity) {
    super(buffer, position, capacity);
  }

  public void update(float[] values) {

    int min = Math.min(values.length, getCapacity());
    for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
      getBuffer().put(i + getPosition(), values[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

And the class for a subpart of IntBuffer

```
public class GLSubIntBuffer extends GLSubBuffer<IntBuffer> {

  public GLSubFloatBuffer(IntBuffer buffer, int position, int capacity) {
    super(buffer, position, capacity);
  }

  public void update(int[] values) {

    int min = Math.min(values.length, getCapacity());
    for (int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
      getBuffer().put(i + getPosition(), values[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

How to refactor the method update() to be able to move it to the main class and remove the two child classes ?

Comment: You'd need to define a generic type for the buffered elements as well, e.g. `GLSubBuffer<E, T extends Buffer<E>)` and then you'd be able to use `E` like `update(E[] values)`. However, this means that you can't use primitive types like `int` and `float` but rather their wrapper counterparts `Integer` and `Float`.

Comment: Note that if `IntBuffer` is defined as `extends Buffer<Integer>` this could still use `int[]` internally. The generic interface would just have to use `Integer` and box/unbox (i.e. convert between `Integer` and `int`).

Comment: @Thomas Using this I will loose performance because I have always to box the array of primitives and then unbox it. I think in this case it  is better to keep as it is now

Comment: @Aguid based on the code above I can guess the `Buffer` declares a method `put` similar to `put(int position, T value)` that is then overridden in both `FloatBuffer` and `IntBuffer`, right? If that's the case how do you deal with boxing/unboxing there?